# How do I Flexmock chaining ActiveRecord::Relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rspec, mocking

I would like to Flexmock a chaining Rails 3 finder scope,

given I have the following call

> User.where(:id => 1).first

and the Flexmock code

> flexmock(User).should_receive(:where).with({:id =>
>   1}).and_return(user)

but I get an error, unknown method 'first' for User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mock `where`

```
where_mock = flexmock('Where', :first => user)
flexmock(User).should_receive(:where).with({:id => 1}).and_return(where_mock)
```